# $(a_n) \rightarrow a$ iff $X_n = a_n \rightarrow X = a$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers.  Let $X_n$ be the degenerate random variable $a_n$.  Show that $(X_n)$ converges in distribution iff $(a_n)$ is convergent.

I am able to show the backwards direction, where if $(a_n)$ converges to $a$ then $X_n$ converges in distribution to the degenerate random variable $X = a$.

However, for the forward direction I am moderately stuck.  I feel like by using the definition of $X_n$ converging in distribution I can show that the sequence must be bounded, but past that I am out of any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

$X_n=a_n$ converges in distribution to $X=a$ if $F_{a_n}(x)\to F_a(x)$ for all $x\neq a$.

We need to show that $a_n\to a$ as $n\to\infty$. That is, for each $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that for every $n\geq N$ we have $|a_n-a|\leq\varepsilon$.

Take arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$. 
$$F_{a_n}(a+\varepsilon)-F_{a_n}(a-\varepsilon)\to F_a(a+\varepsilon)-F_a(a-\varepsilon)=1$$
Note that l.h.s. take values $0$ or $1$ only. In order to converge to $1$, the sequence at the l.h.s. should be equal to $1$ for sufficiently large $n$: there exists $N$ such that for any $n\geq N$
$$
F_{a_n}(a+\varepsilon)-F_{a_n}(a-\varepsilon) = 1.
$$
This equality implies that $a-\varepsilon\leq a_n\leq a+\varepsilon$ or $|a_n-a|\leq\varepsilon$.

Comment: Thanks, the one line I am having difficulty with is just because a sequence of degenerate random variables converges in distribution - how do we know that what it converges to is also a degenerate random variable?

Comment: I read it in the headline of the question. If it is not supposed, then you can get it since each CDF $F_{a_n}(x)$ can take values $0$ or $1$. So all limits of any sequence $F_{a_n}(x)$, if exists, can be either $0$ or $1$. That is limiting distribution, given it exists, is degenerate.